# Is it possible to define an inner product on sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, soft-question, definition, inner-products

Let $(x_n)$, $(y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^\infty$ be sequences.

> Is it possible to define an inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot
>  \rangle$ whereby $\langle (x_n) , (y_n) \rangle = c, c \in \mathbb{R}$?

I am asking this question because while this operation is natural for vectors of arbitrarily finite dimensions, I have never seen it being done for sequences.

Can we possibly take as definition:

$\langle (x_n) , (y_n) \rangle = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + \ldots + x_ny_n + \ldots$?

Comment: Yes we can definitely define one on sequences. Your suggestion won't work though since nothing says that your sum converges.

Comment: See this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space

Comment: @GuyFsone Where does your link address the issue? At first glance, it seems just a small survey of the most famous Banach space structures on subspaces of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$, rather than the whole $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$.

Comment: did really went through the link? it is the same issue . juste he notation of space of sequences is difference. note that if he define the scalar product the way he did it automatically become a banach space

Comment: @GuyFsone Nope. If $u = (1, 1, 1, 1, \ldots)$, then $\left< u, u \right>$ is undefined.

Comment: he say in the text the product is define and exists read the yellow box. so that does not apply

Comment: @GuyFsone You clearly misunderstood the content of the yellow box: it's a question, not a statement. And do you think that with inner product defined as above, $\left< u, u \right> = 1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 1 + \ldots$ exists?

Comment: That case does not applies since $\langle (x_n) , (y_n) \rangle = c, c \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Adayah hello I am still wiating for you explation

Comment: @GuyFsone I don't quite understand your counterargument. The OP asks whether there exists a function $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right> : \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the axioms of an inner product. The assumption that for each $(x_n), (y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ we have $\left< (x_n), (y_n) \right> = c \in \mathbb{R}$ is an informal way to phrase the restriction on the wanted function that for each pair of sequences $\left< (x_n), (y_n) \right>$ must be a real number, not $\infty$ or any divergent series.

Comment: And what I am claiming is that taking the collection oall sequence such that inner product is finite we therefore have an Hilbert space

Comment: @GuyFsone I was about to finish my point in the second comment (it was too long to fit in the first), but you were quicker to answer the first part. :p OK, you're saying that we can pick a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, namely - all sequences such that the series converge - and define the inner product as above. But the question was whether it was possible to define the inner product on the whole space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, not just a subset.

Comment: $H =\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}: \left< (x_n), (x_n) \right> =c\in \Bbb R\}$ is Hilbert do you agree? in this space we just take $ x=y$ in the following  $ \left< (x_n), (y_n) \right> =c\in \Bbb R$

Comment: @GuyFsone I agree. I don't believe it's relevant to the question though.

Comment: THAT SET H I define IS EXACTLY WHAT THE YELLOW BOX IS CONSIDERING. if you think about cauchy schwarz inequality

Comment: The yellow box doesn't define any subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. It only specifies what kind of inner product we're looking for. It even could not define the set $H$ without using the inner product, which we don't yet have and which is the very thing the existence of which the question is about.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a reason why you have never seen it for sequences is that, extending the existing formula for the regular inner product, we would have the following:
$$\langle(x_n),(y_n)\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_ky_k$$
which is an infinite sum, so there is mouch doubt about its convergence - we do not want any vector of our space $v$ with $\langle v,v\rangle=\pm\infty$ or, even worse, $\langle v,u\rangle$ not defined for some $u,v$.

To avoid such problems, we introduce the following spaces:
$$l^p:=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^\infty\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k|^p<+\infty\right.\right\}$$
One can show that $l^p$ is a normed space for every $p\geq1$ (and, actually, for $p=+\infty$), but that only for $p=2$ there is an inner product that generates the norm of that space. So, in the case of $l^2$, the inner product of two **sequences** $x,y\in l^2$ is:
$$\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_ky_k|$$
from which we can take also the formula of the norm:
$$\lVert x\rVert^2=\langle x,x\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k|^2$$
Note that this infinite sum is convergent, since $x\in l^2$. For further reading you can read also [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space).

Comment: There is one superfluous $| \cdot |$ in the definition of $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$ in $\ell^2$. Also, while you discuss the reasons why $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not usually equipped with an inner product, you actually haven't answered wheter it's possible to do so.

Comment: The $|\cdot|$ is a matter of habbit, since the same norms and inner products can be defined over complex sequences, where $z^2\neq|z|^2$. In general, you are right about the "spirit" of the question, so I will try to come up with a complete answer later on today, due to lack of time right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in some inner product and don't care what properties are satisfied by the norm/metric/topology then the question involves only the cardinality. Take a vector space isomorphism from your space onto $l^2$ for example and define the inner product by taking the inner product of the images. Of course, this doesn't give a formula for the inner product.